# Filling an array in PHP Zend Framework and fetching it in the View

Tags: php, arrays, zend-framework, view, fill

I'm trying to fill an array in my PHP ZF2 application controller and pass it onto the view by doing the following:

```
$brandIds = $this->getConfig()['brandIds'];
        $array = array();
        $size = count($brandIds);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++)
        {
            $brand = $this->getBrandModel()->getBrandById($brandIds[$i]);
            $array = array_fill($i,$size, $brand);
        }
        $signInSession = $this->signInUser->user;
        if(empty($signInSession))
        {
            $this->redirect()->toUrl('/index/landing');
        }
        $viewModel = new ViewModel();
        $viewModel->setVariable("b",$array);
        return $viewModel;
```

Please note that:

```
$this->getConfig()['brandIds']
```

is an static array which I've predefined in the config file like following:

```
  "brandIds" => array(
        "AUTO" => 16,
        "FINANCE" => 18,
        "EVENTS" => 19,
        "HEALTH" => 21,
        "GADGETS" => 25
    ),
```

And in the view I'm doing the following:

```
  <?php foreach ($brands as $bId){ ?>
                <h1> <?=$bId?> </h1>
               <?php }?>
```

But when I open up the view in my browser, nothing appears. My question here is, or more of a problem is that I don't understand why nothing shows up on my view. Also, how can I access each element of this array which is fetched from the DB. Like if the table in the DB has column called "id", I'd like to access it by following:

```
<?=$bId['id']?>
```

And write it out on my view (this is just an example, I wouldn't actually print ID from DB lol)...

Can someone help me out with this guys?

Thanks heaps!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all the name of the variable is `b` and not `bId` as stated on this line `$viewModel->setVariable("b",$array);`.

Then to print the said value, you have to call in your view `$this->b['id'];`

Hope this'll work,

Comment: Oddly? It works now... Not sure why I was unable to access the elements of the array...